# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, tensorflow.js

```
'''
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<!-- Load Posenet -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img id='cat' src='cat.jpg '/>
</body>
<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>
var flipHorizontal = false;

var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

posenet.load().then(function(net) {
const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
flipHorizontal: true
});
return pose;
}).then(function(pose){
console.log(pose);
})
</script>
</html>
'''
```

Above is html file using which I am trying out posenet from tensorflow js. 
Following is the error which I received when I tried to open the above file in google chrome.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.
at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:176404
at qt (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:55726)
at vi (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:176377)
at t.uploadPixelDataToTexture (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:181200)
at Object.kernelFunc (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:480876)
at h (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:42226)
at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:42907
at t.scopedRun (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:40845)
at t.runKernelFunc (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:42726)
at t.runKernel (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs:2:41280)
```

Following is the error when the html file is opened in firefox

```
'''
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs
Source Map URL: tf.min.js.map 
'''
```

I am a beginner and I am not able to understand the above error. I am trying to get the pose coordinates from the console in the browser but I just keep getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`crossorigin='anonymous'` needs to be added to the image tag

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
  <!-- Load Posenet -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id='cat' src='https://i.imgur.com/jlFgGpe.jpg' crossorigin='anonymous' />
</body>
<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>
  var flipHorizontal = false;

  var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

  posenet.load().then(function(net) {
    const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
      flipHorizontal: true
    });
    return pose;
  }).then(function(pose) {
    console.log(pose);
  })
</script>

</html>
```

To use an image locally, the image needs to be served by a server allowing cors. http-server can be used with the command line

```
http-server -c1 --cors .
```

```js
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <!-- Load Posenet -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id='cat' src=' http://127.0.0.1:8080/temp.png' crossorigin="anonymous" />
</body>
<!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
<script>

    var flipHorizontal = false;

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

    imageElement.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

    posenet.load().then(function (net) {
        const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
            flipHorizontal: true
        });
        return pose;
    }).then(function (pose) {
        console.log(pose);
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you still have the same error when using the crossorigin attribute ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Code given by you works fine but I need to use a image which is local in my system. Can you suggest me how to to it.

Comment: Locally, you will need to serve the image by a server and allow cors

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I am able to use my local images. Everything works just fine.

Comment: How to modify the above code to use a webcam video instead of a image. The demo code from github posenet repo is too complex and I do not require all those features.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my **react app** and **tensorflow.js** but i only realised that i was missing the `crossOrigin` prop or attribute as **edkeveked** mentioned. So i solved my problem by modifying the `img` tag and put the attribute or property `crossOrigin`  as follows:

```
<img crossOrigin='anonymous' ... />
```

**edkeveked**'s answer is the best

**Good luck** ✔✔✨✨