# Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext'. Access to image at 'imageurl.com' from origin 'exampale.com' has been blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, tensorflow.js

i have seen this answer:
[Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577407/uncaught-in-promise-domexception-failed-to-execute-teximage2d-on-webgl2ren)

it does help on local made server but i am trying to make an extension/addon so i run the script on different server and if i try to set the crossOrigin attribute to 'anonymous' it says:

> Access to image at
> 'https://dl5zpyw5k3jeb.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/48663430/1/?bust=1596323497&width=560'
> from origin 'https://www.petfinder.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

my manifest:

```
{ 
    "manifest_version" : 2, 
    "name" : "tf", 
    "description": "tf",
    "version" : "0.2", 
    "content_scripts" : [
        { 
            "matches" : [ "<all_urls>"], 
            "js" : ["tfjs.js", "coco-ssd.js", "content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

my code:

```
const img = document.getElementByTagName('img');
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
cocoSsd.load().then(model => {
    let canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
          ctx.strokeRect(predictions[0].bbox[0], predictions[0].bbox[1], predictions[0].bbox[2], predictions[0].bbox[3]);
      }
      let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      img.src = dataURL;
      });
    }
  });
```

Ty in advance

Comment: Assuming this URL is allowed in `permissions` of your manifest.json, you can load it only in your extension pages such as the background script, popup script, and so on.

Comment: Hi not sure how it should help edited my question

Comment: The thing is, content scripts can't make cross-origin requests in new Chrome so you'll have to use an extension page. For example you can add an iframe to the web page, pointing to an html file inside your extension directory exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). That iframe will have a chrome-extension:// URL and will be able to make cross-origin requests for URLs listed in `permissions`.

Comment: srry for being nooby did'nt understood what should i do...
i need to acces images in any give web page and send them to model.detect(img)
how an iframe can help me?

Comment: Well, I gave the hints and keywords so you can use them to find examples and more info...

Comment: ty wOxxOm works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wOxxOm said the answer:

> The thing is, content scripts can't make cross-origin requests in new
> Chrome so you'll have to use an extension page. For example you can
> add an iframe to the web page, pointing to an html file inside your
> extension directory exposed via web_accessible_resources. That iframe
> will have a chrome-extension:// URL and will be able to make
> cross-origin requests for URLs listed in permissions